# How to configure certificate for fastapi app

Tags: python, docker, deployment, ssl-certificate, fastapi

I created two applications (backend (fastapi. Works on 8000 port), frontend (reactjs. Works on 80 port)) they are communicate each with other.

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  frontend:
    container_name: "frontend"
    build: 
      context: ./frontend
    stop_signal: SIGTERM
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./uploads:/app/uploads
    networks:
      - good_network
    depends_on:
      - backend

  backend:
    container_name: "backend"
    build:
      context: ./backend
    stop_signal: SIGTERM
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    networks:
      - good_network
    volumes:
      - ./uploads:/app/uploads
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  postgres:
    container_name: "postgres"
    image: postgres:16.0
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -d sugar -U postgres" ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 5s
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - good_network

networks:
  good_network:

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

help me with configuration a certificate :(.

My tries:

```
uvicorn.run(..., ssl_keyfile="./privkey.pem", ssl_certfile="./fullchain.pem")  # Problem with cors :/
```

I've tried to use certbot, but i created a certfiles, but i didn't understand what to do with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sloved this via nginx and subdomain for backend.

For feature readers:

```
# Number of simultaneously processed connections
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

    # for example configuration for your python application
    # port means where future requests 
    # from the below specified block will be forwarded
    upstream web {
        server <your_host>:<application_port>;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        server_name <your_host>;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://web;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
        }
    }

    # This is a server configuration block in Nginx that determines how
    # to handle requests for a specific domain or IP address and port. 
    # In this case, the server listens for requests on port 443 
    # using an SSL certificate to secure the connection and passes them 
    # to the backend server named "back" via HTTP using the proxy_pass directive.
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name <your_host>;
        
        # your cert files (for example, generated by certbot)
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/<your_host>/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/<your_host>/privkey.pem;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/<your_host>/chain.pem;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://web;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        }
}
```

My nginx.conf:

```
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

    # backend

    upstream back {
        server back.mysite.ru:8000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name back.mysite.ru;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://back;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name back.mysite.ru;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/back.mysite.ru/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/back.mysite.ru/privkey.pem;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/back.mysite.ru/chain.pem;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://back;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        }
    }

    # frontend

    upstream front {
        server mysite.ru:80;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mysite.ru;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://front;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name mysite.ru;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.ru/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.ru/privkey.pem;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.ru/chain.pem;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://front;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        }
    }
}
```

My nginx in docker container:

```
nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
    depends_on:
      - frontend
      - backend
```

This docker container runs Nginx inside the container and configures it to listen on port 443. The container also mounts a local /etc/letsencrypt directory inside the container so that Nginx can use SSL certificates stored in this directory.

My nginx Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to include this in a place where you define "app".
This adds CORS middleware to allow origins and requests to come.

```
app.add_middleware(
CORSMiddleware,
allow_origins=["*"],  # Set this to the specific origin(s) you want to allow
allow_credentials=True,
allow_methods=["*"],  # Set this to the specific HTTP methods you want to allow
allow_headers=["*"],  # Set this to the specific HTTP headers you want to allow
)
```